# Sharepoint 2013 - External List view/edit item in modal dialog

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, 2013, xslt, modal-dialog, external-list

I have an External List, reading from a WCF.

When I open an item (view item), I want it to open in a modal dialog.

The External Data Source has 'read item' and 'read list' set up from WCF services.

When opened in browser, the link for all the items looks like following:

```
<a class="ms-listlink ms-draggable" onfocus="OnLink(this)" href="http://swsudc07:9100/_layouts/15/listform.aspx?PageType=4&amp;ListId=%7B6C76DFC6%2D7304%2D451D%2D80E8%2D08656B4209C1%7D&amp;ID=__cg40000300k82000200020002000200530003000300030043003300&amp;ContentTypeID=0x0" onclick="EditLink2(this,1);return false;" target="_self" dragid="4" draggable="true">    500043</a>
```

Basically I want to override the onclick action to NOT use the EditLink2 function.

When I edit the page in SPD, the page looks like this:
I tried to find the XSL for WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart, but had no luck..

```
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" FrameType="None" ID="Main" Title="loc:Main"><ZoneTemplate>
<WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart runat="server" ViewFlag="" ViewSelectorFetchAsync="False" InplaceSearchEnabled="False" ServerRender="False" ClientRender="True" InitialAsyncDataFetch="False" WebId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" IsClientRender="False" GhostedXslLink="main.xsl" ViewGuid="{44BC9D47-357D-49F0-A47E-95A422B81350}" EnableOriginalValue="False" DisplayName="plist Read List" ViewContentTypeId="" Default="TRUE" ListName="{6C76DFC6-7304-451D-80E8-08656B4209C1}" ListId="6c76dfc6-7304-451d-80e8-08656b4209c1" PageType="PAGE_DEFAULTVIEW" PageSize="-1" UseSQLDataSourcePaging="True" DataSourceID="" ShowWithSampleData="False" AsyncRefresh="False" ManualRefresh="False" AutoRefresh="False" AutoRefreshInterval="60" Title="plist2" FrameType="Default" SuppressWebPartChrome="False" Description="" IsIncluded="True" ZoneID="Main" PartOrder="2" FrameState="Normal" AllowRemove="True" AllowZoneChange="True" AllowMinimize="True" AllowConnect="True" AllowEdit="True" AllowHide="True" IsVisible="True" CatalogIconImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/itebl.png?rev=23" TitleUrl="/Lists/plist2" DetailLink="/Lists/plist2" HelpLink="" HelpMode="Modeless" Dir="Default" PartImageSmall="" MissingAssembly="Cannot import this Web Part." PartImageLarge="/_layouts/15/images/itebl.png?rev=23" IsIncludedFilter="" ExportControlledProperties="False" ConnectionID="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" ID="g_44bc9d47_357d_49f0_a47e_95a422b81350" ExportMode="NonSensitiveData" __MarkupType="vsattributemarkup" __WebPartId="{44BC9D47-357D-49F0-A47E-95A422B81350}" __AllowXSLTEditing="true" WebPart="true" Height="" Width=""><ParameterBindings>

  <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_sortdir" Location="Postback;Connection"/>
            <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_sortfield" Location="Postback;Connection"/>
            <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_startposition" Location="Postback" DefaultValue=""/>
            <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_firstrow" Location="Postback;Connection"/>
            <ParameterBinding Name="OpenMenuKeyAccessible" Location="Resource(wss,OpenMenuKeyAccessible)" />
            <ParameterBinding Name="open_menu" Location="Resource(wss,open_menu)" />
            <ParameterBinding Name="select_deselect_all" Location="Resource(wss,select_deselect_all)" />
            <ParameterBinding Name="idPresEnabled" Location="Resource(wss,idPresEnabled)" /><ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_LIST)" /><ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_DEFAULT)" /></ParameterBindings>
<DataFields>
</DataFields>
<XmlDefinition>
<View Name="{44BC9D47-357D-49F0-A47E-95A422B81350}" DefaultView="TRUE" MobileView="TRUE" MobileDefaultView="TRUE" Type="HTML" DisplayName="plist Read List" Url="/Lists/plist2/GetPrismJobList.aspx" Level="1" BaseViewID="1" ContentTypeID="0x" ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/generic.png?rev=23" ><Method Name="GetPrismJobList"/><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name="QM_CUST_CODE"/></OrderBy></Query><ViewFields><FieldRef Name="QM_NUMBER"/><FieldRef Name="QM_QUOTE_JOB"/><FieldRef Name="QM_TITLE"/><FieldRef Name="QM_JOB_STATUS"/><FieldRef Name="QM_JOB_QTY"/><FieldRef Name="QM_REQD_DATE"/></ViewFields><RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit><Aggregations Value="Off"/><JSLink>clienttemplates.js</JSLink><XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink><Toolbar Type="Standard"/></View></XmlDefinition>
</WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart>

</ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
```

I'm very new to Sharepoint, not sure if I need to provide any other information.
Please let me know.
Thanks!!